# What is memoized in Spek?

Tags: java, testing, kotlin, spek

Spek documentation references

```
As a best practice you typically want test values to be unique for each test this can be done by using a lateinit variable and assigning it within a beforeEachTest. lateinit var calculator: Calculator

beforeEachTest {
    calculator = Calculator()
}

To make it more concise, Spek provides memoized to do the same thing:


val calculator by memoized { Calculator() }
```

What exactly is memoized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memoization is remembering (caching) the result of a function call with a given set of parameter values so that if that same function is called again with the same parameter values, the cached result will be returned rather than having to re-run the function. It's an optimisation technique.

See more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

So in the example above Spek wraps the call to construct a `Calculator` in its `memoized` function, meaning that it will only construct it once, and thereafter calls to `calculator` will re-use that existing instance. And in terms of how you'd generally use it in a test, that would give you the same behaviour as constructing a new `Calculator` in `beforeEachTest`, but in a more concise way.